# How to make dynamic input fields work with drag & drop

Tags: dynamic

I have an application using `InputField` to allow a user to dynamically update a data structure. In some cases the user will want to remove a string from one field and paste it into another. If this is done using cut and paste everything works okay, and the underlying data updates to reflect what is seen in the GUI. However, if the string is moved using drag and drop, the `Dynamic` in the source field does not appear to register the change of contents, although the destination field works as expected.

Here's an example:

```
test = {"string", ""};
Column[{
  InputField[Dynamic[test[[1]]], String],
  InputField[Dynamic[test[[2]]], String],
  Dynamic[test]
  }]
```

[image]

If I now drag and drop the string from the upper field into the lower field I get this:

[image]

The upper input field is now empty but `test[[1]]` still contains `"string"`. This is a problem, because normally the `Dynamic[test]` line won't be there so the user relies on the input fields to correctly show the actual contents of `test`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: what do you mean by drag and drop? Am I missing something? Also, I assume that `ContinuousAction->True` does not work too, does it"?

Comment: What OS or mma version allows you to drag and drop these fields?

Comment: @Kuba, thank you - `ContinuousAction` fixes it. Please consider posting that as an answer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, version 9 on windows 7. Pretty sure it worked with version 7 on XP too. You do have to have drag and drop editing enabled in preferences.

Comment: @SimonWoods oh, +1, I wasn't aware of the drag&drop built-in functionality :) each day something new :)

Comment: I forgot about that option.  I think years ago I tried it but I had too many accidental edits with it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. I too tried it awhile back, but _Mathematica_'s inept undo facility made it too risky.

Comment: Unfortunately, my experiments with an `EventHandler` wrapper to handle `"MouseDragged"` failed to identify drag-and-drop events, so I would say this is another GUI functionality that cannot be handled correctly from within *Mathematica*, just like focusgain/loss, key release, etc.

Comment: @m_goldberg, I can't argue with the "risky" comment, you do have to be careful not to drop your selection in the wrong place or it will simply vanish. I did try turning it off for a while, but in the end decided that the convenience outweighed the risk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The descriprion of the problem seemed to me similar to other issues I've faced in the past.

```
ContinuousAction->True
```

option for `InputField` helped me then and OP confirms that it helps in his case too.

So at the end, MWE introduced by Simon Woods should be expanded to:

```
Column[{
        InputField[Dynamic[test[[1]]], String, ContinuousAction -> True], 
        InputField[Dynamic[test[[2]]], String, ContinuousAction -> True], 
        Dynamic[test]
      }]
```

Comment: Please consider editing your answer to show where in Simon Woods' code the option should be applied.

Comment: @m_goldberg both `InputField` expressions.

Comment: @m_goldberg You're right.